# Discord.JS bot does not respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My Discrod.JS bot is online but not responding. This is the code-

```
// require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// create a new Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// when the client is ready, run this code
// this event will only trigger one time after logging in
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

module.exports = function(controller) {
  controller.hears(
    "!appreciates",
    ["direct_mention", "mention"],
    (bot, message) => {
      let response;
      let sender = message.user;
      let recipient = message.mentions.users
        .filter(user => user.bot === false)
        .last();
      let responses = [
        `Hey, ${sender}, I appreciate you!  :heart_eyes:`,
        `Hey, ${sender}, I appreciate your enthusiasm!  :muscle:`,
        `Hey, ${sender}, I appreciate your commands!  :wink:`,
        `Hey, ${sender}, I appreciate your particaption! :grinning:`,
        `Hey, ${sender}, I appreciate all your works! :blush:`,
        `Hey, ${sender}, I appreciate everything you do. :star_struck:`
      ];

      response = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];

      bot.reply(message, response);
    }
  );
};
client.login('app token');
```

There is no error in the console. The only message in the console is "Ready!". I have also checked if Discord.JS NPM module is installed and it is.

Comment: Did you ever call the function?

Comment: With the call() method? No, I did not. The code you see is complete, by the way.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use a message event handler? (e.g. `client.on('message', message => { ... });`)

Comment: No, no special reason. I was just rewriting an old bot (which is still working) and it had this code.

Comment: Well, at the moment, your code is exporting a function that accepts a "controller" that has the ability to listen to messages. Either add that functionality in, or switch to using a message event handler (as shown in my above comment).

Answer (score 1):

To make your bot be able to do something when receiving a message you need `client.on('message',message =>{//your code}`

example:

```
client.on('message',message =>{

//execute a command
message.channel.send("hello world");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an event to be triggered. In this case, you want it to reply. So you need the message event.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    //

    //This is where your function would go
    //

});
```